# In Excel 2013 Is there a way to code an auto-complete function ibased on values in another tab

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to create an auto complete cell in Excel for the resource name. The list is too long for a custom list and I really do not want a drop down list as in data validation. Does someone have an example of a formula or VB code that will do this that they would be willing to share?

so, if the control tab has two columns defined (Role, Name) where role is Tester, Developer, Manager and the name is a list staff names.

On Capture tab in column Name I want to be able to start typing and have Excel locate names from control and populate the name in capture.

Can this be done? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a text box with this functionality.  You use code based on the keypress event of the textbox to do the lookup and suggestion.  Then you use the change_selection event of the worksheet to relocate the textbox to align with the cell and place the cursor in the textbox when a cell in that column is selected.

Comment: I'm interested to know more, can you please elaborate your answer when u have time.